# Multiple audio streams supported by camera

Tags: video-streaming, audio-streaming

I have a camera which can support two video streams with different codecs and has different settings for both the video streams.

Along with the video stream configuration on the camera I can also configure audio streams. However I am not sure whether changing the video streams in a player will also change the corresponding audio stream or not.

I would like to know whether this is possible or not and what could be the reasons a camera would not support this.

Comment: What does the player have to do with the camera?  Can you elaborate on what exactly you're doing?  This camera is connected... via USB?  You're choosing the video codec with... what API?  And, this camera is doing an audio codec?  It's not just sending PCM samples for your software to encode?  That would be a very strange camera.

Comment: @Brad the things is this camera is added to a very popular video surveillance product and is added in the UI respective to the product. I can see a live and recorded stream for the camera. What my query is when a camera streams audio and video both do they go as a one stream setting or camera's in general dont support multiple audio streams like they do for video streams.

Comment: Alright, so you have a camera hooked up via a network... I still don't understand at all what you're asking.